# Avoid repeating variable setup in bash

Tags: bash, sqlite

Bash newbie here! How do I avoid repeating the "PASSGEN=$(</dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c12)" each time in this bash script excerpt?

```
sqlite variables.db "create table passwords (name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT);"
PASSGEN=$(</dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c12)
sqlite variables.db "insert into passwords (name,value) values ('BOOKSTACK_MYSQL_ROOT', '$PASSGEN');"
PASSGEN=$(</dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c12)
sqlite variables.db "insert into passwords (name,value) values ('BOOKSTACK_MYSQL', '$PASSGEN');"
PASSGEN=$(</dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c12)
sqlite variables.db "insert into passwords (name,value) values ('BORG_PASSPHRASE', '$PASSGEN');"
PASSGEN=$(</dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c12)
sqlite variables.db "insert into passwords (name,value) values ('CODE_SERVER_PASS', '$PASSGEN');"
PASSGEN=$(</dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c12)
sqlite variables.db "insert into passwords (name,value) values ('CODE_SERVER_SUDO_PASS', '$PASSGEN');"
PASSGEN=$(</dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c12)
sqlite variables.db "insert into passwords (name,value) values ('EXPORTARR_TOKEN', '$PASSGEN');"
PASSGEN=$(</dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c12)
sqlite variables.db "insert into passwords (name,value) values ('FLAME_PASS', '$PASSGEN');"
PASSGEN=$(</dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c12)
sqlite variables.db "insert into passwords (name,value) values ('FLIGHTAIRMAP_INSTALL_PASS', '$PASSGEN');"
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to write a function:

```
function generate_password {
    </dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c12
}
```

Then, your code snippet becomes:

```
sqlite variables.db "create table passwords (name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT);"
sqlite variables.db "insert into passwords (name,value) values ('BOOKSTACK_MYSQL_ROOT', '$(generate_password)');"
sqlite variables.db "insert into passwords (name,value) values ('BOOKSTACK_MYSQL', '$(generate_password)');"
sqlite variables.db "insert into passwords (name,value) values ('BORG_PASSPHRASE', '$(generate_password)');"
# ...
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the super fast and concise help!

Comment: No problem. If this solution is what you need, select this answer as "accepted answer".

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use a loop for the table insertions.  Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
sqlite variables.db "create table passwords (name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT);"

for name in BOOKSTACK_MYSQL_ROOT BOOKSTACK_MYSQL BORG_PASSPHRASE    \
            CODE_SERVER_PASS CODE_SERVER_SUDO_PASS EXPORTARR_TOKEN  \
            FLAME_PASS FLIGHTAIRMAP_INSTALL_PASS
do
    passgen=$(</dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c12)
    sqlite variables.db "insert into passwords (name,value) values ('$name', '$passgen');"
done
```

- See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/4154375) for an explanation of why I replaced `PASSGEN` with `passgen`.